# Any Ruby models to traverse DOM's quickly?

Tags: ruby, dom, rubygems, nokogiri

Does anyone know of any Ruby libraries/gems that allow you to traverse a DOM quickly?

I need something which is fast, and doesn't have a lot of dependencies. I've been trying to use Nokogiri, but I'm concerned with the number of 'bug segmentation faults' I've been getting.

Answer (score 1):

[Hpricot](http://hpricot.com/) is a personal favourite of mine.

Comment: just asked my boss about this. suppose to be stable, but slower than nokogiri. then again.. there's no c code.. ideally, need something with the best of both worlds.